# How to update an array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

say I have a variable

```
 data=[] 

 //this variable is an array of object like 
 data = [
     {name:'a',value:'aa'},
     {name:'b',value:'bb'}
 ]

 // the data structrue can not be changed and the initial value is empty
```

now I want to update the data

```
 function updateData(){
     if(!data.length){
         data.push(arguments)
     }
     else{
         //this parts really confuse me
     }

 }
```

this function must accept any number of arguments,and the order of the objects in data dose not matters
**update rule**:

1. update the objects value to the arguments value if they have the same name.
2. add the arguments to the data if none of the object in data have the same name.

how to write this function?

```
 updateData([
     {name:'a',value:'aa'},
     {name:'b',value:'bb'}
 ])
 // expect data = [
           {name:'a',value:'aa'},
           {name:'b',value:'bb'}
           ]

 updateData([
     {name:'a',value:'aa'},
     {name:'b',value:'DD'},
     {name:'c',value:'cc'}
] )
 // expect data = [
           {name:'a',value:'aa'},
           {name:'b',value:'DD'},
           {name:'c',value:'cc'}
           ]
```

Comment: nice homework question

Comment: you missed a comma between `{name:'a',value:'aa'}` and `{name:'b',value:'bb'}` at many places

Comment: Its a real project question, I need to dynamiclly add jquery file upload's formData

Comment: How about loop through array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ashutosh Upadhyay suggested use a name value pair instead of an array:

```
var data ={};

var updateData=function(){
  var len = arguments.length,
  i=0;
  for(i=0;i<len;i++){
    data[arguments[i].name]=arguments[i].value;
  }
};
updateData(
 {name:"a",value:"22"}, 
 {name:"b",value:"2"}, 
 {name:"c",value:"3"}, 
 {name:"a",value:"1"} // the new value for a
);
for(key in data){
  if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    console.log(key + "=" + data[key]);
  }
}
```

Just read your comment about the array, so if you have to have an array you can:

```
var data = [];
function findIndex(name){
  var i = 0;
  for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i].name===name){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return i;
}
function updateData(){
  var i = 0;
  for(i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
    data[findIndex(arguments[i].name)]=arguments[i];
  }
}
updateData(
 {name:"a",value:"22"}, 
 {name:"b",value:"2"}, 
 {name:"c",value:"3"}, 
 {name:"a",value:"1"} // the new value for a
);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok you might want to do something like that?

```
var data = [
     {name:'a',value:'aa'},
     {name:'b',value:'bb'}
 ];

 function updateData(obj){
  var objFound_bool = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(obj.name === data[i].name){
      objFound_bool = true;
      data[i].value =obj.value ;
    }
  }
  if(!objFound_bool){
    data.push(obj)
  }
 }
```

Comment: You can just break if the if statemnet is true and after the for loop do `data[i]=obj;`

Comment: please note that the updateData function must accept any number of argument and tha initial value of data is empty

Comment: Hi, I have a similar scenario and can you help on it please?

Answer (score 1):

Since order doesn't really matter to you, better choice would be an object hash instead of an array. Something like

```
{
  'a':{name:'a', value: 'aa'}
}
```

This will let you search easily based on keys and you can update the hash.

You can even employ above to your situation. Convert the array into a temporary object hash as above, do necessary changes, and convert back to an array. This will be more efficient as it will save you searches through the array.

```
 var output_array = [];
 for (var key in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      output_array.push(obj[key]);
   }
 }
```

Comment: this is what I have in mind, but It seems even harder to convert the object back to array, can you give me an example

Answer (score 1):

if names are unique you could define `data` as a map and just add the values using the name as key:

```
 var data={
     'a':'aa',
     'b':'bb'
 }

function updateData() {
   for (var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) { //for each argument...
      for (key in arguments[i]) { //we'll put each pair (key,value) in the data
         data[key]=arguments[i][key];
      }
   }

}
```

EDIT: function to transform to an array

```
 function toArray() {
    var array=[];
    for (key in data) {
       array.push({name:key,value:data[key]});
    }
    return array;
 }
```

Comment: like I said the variable's data structrue can not be changed, if you have to change it to make the function easier then you have to change it back

Comment: sorry, I forgot that part.. here it is now

Comment: I tried your function and Its wrong (var key in arguments[i]),this is wrong

Comment: Are you sure? I've C&P that code in the Chrome and Firefox (Firebug) consoles and it worked in both browsers.

Comment: the updateDate() function is right but the toArray function is wrong; it will output something like [{name:'name','value':'a'},{name:'value',value:'aa'}]

Comment: It's what I understand from your explanation: an array of objects that have name and value